# subtract offset from DateTime (date time to UTC)

Tags: sql, sql-server, timezone-offset, datetimeoffset

Dear DB gurus once again I need help.

I have the following table and I need to use the information in the Offset column to turn the different local times to GMT

```
Order Time          Offset
2016-05-03 10:08:22 +0200
2016-05-03 10:08:22 +0300
2016-05-03 13:11:26 +0200
2016-05-03 11:07:27 +0200
2016-05-03 14:22:35 +0200
2016-05-03 16:31:36 +0300
```

the result that I aim at is something like this

```
Order Time          
2016-05-03 08:08:22
2016-05-03 07:08:22 
2016-05-03 11:11:26 
2016-05-03 09:07:27 
2016-05-03 12:22:35 
2016-05-03 13:31:36
```

Actually I need  to calculate the time by UTC.

For example `2016-05-03 11:25:26` with `+0300` offset needs to become `2016-05-03 08:25:26` UTC.

Comment: why your offset is stored as +0200 and no as +02:00?

Comment: it comes from a file that is loaded that way into DB

Comment: what are data types of the columns? (I'm guessing datetime and varchar)

Comment: Good guess :)  the columns are order time - datetime and offset - varchar

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT TODATETIMEOFFSET([Order Time], '-' +
            substring(t.Offset, 2, len(t.Offset) - 2) + ':' +
            substring(t.Offset, len(t.Offset) - 2, 2))
FROM yourtable t
```

Comment: sorry may be I wasn't clear with my explanation I need actually to calculate the time by UTC .For example 2016-05-03 11:25:26 with +0300 offset needs to become 2016-05-03 08:25:26 UTC

Answer (score 0):

I've used `LEFT` to get the sign and the number of hours and `LEFT` + `RIGHT` to get the sign and the number of minutes, then used `CAST` to changed the `varchar` values to `int` values, and from there it's just a simple `DATEADD` for minutes and `DATEADD` for hours:

**Declare sample table**

```
DECLARE @YourTable As Table
(
    [Order Time] datetime,
    Offset varchar(6)
)
```

**Populate sample table**

```
INSERT INTO @YourTable VALUES 
('2016-05-03 10:08:22', '+0200'),
('2016-05-03 10:08:22', '+0300'),
('2016-05-03 13:11:26', '-0200'), -- Note: - 2 hours
('2016-05-03 11:07:27', '+0200'),
('2016-05-03 14:22:35', '+0200'),
('2016-05-03 16:31:36', '-0325') -- Note: - 3 hours 25 minutes
```

**Select**

```
SELECT  Offset, [Order Time],
        DATEADD(HOUR, 
                -CAST(LEFT(Offset, LEN(Offset)-2) as int), 
                DATEADD(MINUTE, 
                        -CAST(LEFT(Offset, 1) + RIGHT(Offset, 2) as int), 
                        [Order Time])
                ) As [Order Time UTC]
FROM @YourTable
```

**Results**

```
Offset  Order Time                  Order Time UTC
------  -----------------------     -----------------------
+0200   2016-05-03 10:08:22.000     2016-05-03 08:08:22.000
+0300   2016-05-03 10:08:22.000     2016-05-03 07:08:22.000
-0200   2016-05-03 13:11:26.000     2016-05-03 15:11:26.000 -- Note: - 2 hours
+0200   2016-05-03 11:07:27.000     2016-05-03 09:07:27.000
+0200   2016-05-03 14:22:35.000     2016-05-03 12:22:35.000
-0325   2016-05-03 16:31:36.000     2016-05-03 19:56:36.000 -- Note: - 3 hours and 25 minutes
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
;WITH cte AS (
SELECT *
FROM (VALUES
('2016-05-03 10:08:22', '+0200'),
('2016-05-03 10:08:22', '+0300'),
('2016-05-03 13:11:26', '+0200'),
('2016-05-03 11:07:27', '+0200'),
('2016-05-03 14:22:35', '+0200'),
('2016-05-03 16:31:36', '+0300')
) AS t([Order Time], Offset)
)

SELECT CAST(SWITCHOFFSET(TODATETIMEOFFSET([Order Time], STUFF(Offset,4,0,':')),'-00:00')as datetime)
FROM cte
```

Output:

```
2016-05-03 08:08:22.000
2016-05-03 07:08:22.000
2016-05-03 11:11:26.000
2016-05-03 09:07:27.000
2016-05-03 12:22:35.000
2016-05-03 13:31:36.000
```